# Element type test must be declared error in testNG.xml file

Tags: testng.xml

step 1: Created a simple testng script
step 2: created .xml file
step 3: opened testng.xlm file

saw the error message "Element type test must be declared" in testNG.xml file.
Actions taken :
changed the dtd version
updated the testNG in project level
created a new maven project still see the same.
Any suggestions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FpOS.png)
this is the xml file